# Installing bower using Sudo

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, terminal, bower-install

I did try and find a matching topic but couldn't find one. 
I am trying to install Bower, never used it before but wanted to get into it and same time learn more Sass on Bootstrap so thats why I'm installing it.

Installed npm, opened terminal and typed in the following:

```
npm install -g bower
```

But i get some errors and I'm told: to run as root/Administrator.

Looked around a bit and found some people saying to install it as Sudo, would i then use the line:

```
sudo -s npm install -g bower
```

(is that correct?)

and is it the right thing to do, there are plenty of warnings around the net about being very careful when using sudo commands so i wanted to just check before doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

option `-s` specifies the shell to run, that is something like: `sudo -s /bin/bash npm ...`, but you don't need that at all, use your default shell:

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Yes, it is fine and accepted pattern to use `sudo` for `npm`.

Installing software globally always carries some risk, but nobody reported anything very nasty regarding `sudo npm` as a consequence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, installed now and works.